# Best Practice: handle passing commands from child object to parent object, grandparent object, etc. VBNET

Tags: vb.net, parent-child

I have a parent control which instantiates children controls, which in turn may instantiate further children. What is the best way to pass commands or values from a grand-child back up to the top parent control? Consider this example:

A child control has a button to delete itself. But the method for the actual deletion, removal from the GUI, etc., is all handled by the top parent out of necessity.

Here are the two ways I've facilitated this, both of which work:

1. When a parent instantiates a child, it passes a reference to itself to the child. This lets the child now call public members of the parent. In code this would look something like:

```
'*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~
'in the parent object
Dim child as new ChildObject
child.setParent(me)
'*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~

'in the child object
public sub setParent(byref p as parentObject)
        myParent = p
end sub

'now the child can interact with the parent
'for example:
myParent.deleteMe()
```

This works OK for when there is a single level depth. But in cases where you've got several levels, it is clunky and you'd be doing something like:

```
myParent.myParent.myParent.deleteMe()
```

Not cool.

2. The other way I've facilitated this is with a public variable that is monitored by a high speed timer in the top parent. If the child needs some parent method run, then it flags a bool to TRUE, which the timer monitors and then calls the appropriate method. But this entails a public variable which I would prefer to avoid using. This method also uses continuous a timer which consumes resources.

Question:

Are these acceptable ways to accomplish the goal? Is there a better way? Or is the fact that I'm even needing to do this indicative of an overall design flaw?

Comment: Are these WinForm controls?  If so, they already have a `Parent` (control) property.

Comment: These are WPF controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't work much with WPF, but I believe that you could use the [VisualTreeHelper.GetParent Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent?view=netframework-4.8) to *walk up* the visual tree to find a parent of a specific type.

```
Public Shared Function FindProgenitor(Of T As DependencyObject)(child As DependencyObject) As T
  Dim parent As DependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child)
  Do Until parent Is Nothing OrElse TypeOf parent Is T
    parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent)
  Loop
  Return DirectCast(parent, T)
End Function
```

Assuming the progenitor control is of type RootControl, then a usage case in a child control would look something like:

```
Dim myParent As RootControl = FindProgenitor(Of RootControl)(Me)
If myParent IsNot Nothing Then
   ' call method on RootControl instance myParent
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

When you link the Child Control to the Parent as you have shown `child.setParent(Me)`, you could have another Property and link to the TopParent Control from the current Parent (Call it what you like). eg. `me.TopControl = p.TopControl` You obviously then need to determine/set the TopControl before adding all the children.

Then you can call it anywhere like `me.TopControl.deleteMe()`